# Stop "encodeURIComponent" from converting HTML break into carriage return symbol

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I am in the process of creating a forum. I am doing this without tutorials to test my php, mysql, javascript knowledge and it's going well however I've encountered 1 problem:

I am using encodeURIComponent() to sanitise the posted forum text before sending it via ajax to my PHP and finally through to MySQL. I've noticed that this changes any new lines into the literal carriage return symbol (down and left arrow).

When this forum text is then returned from the database through an ajax request I can see this symbol in my console window but the javascript simply ignores it.

How can I make it recognise this symbol?

[Image of the console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAQDw.png)

[Image of the output HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu0wg.png)

Comment: Are you sure Javascript ignores it? It shouldn't. But HTML does. Did you mean that?

Comment: You're right, looking at the "Elements" tab it appears that the carriage return symbol is converted into new lines on the console but that the HTML is simply ignoring them. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: No, but there is a work-around (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is always ignoring carriage returns, because you are meant to use `<p></p>` and `<br/>` for that.

The easiest way to fix your issue is to just replace all carriage returns with line breaks again. You can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) with PHP or [`str.replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) with JavaScript.

Comment: Thats great, do you happen to know what the carriage return symbol in php or javascript would be? Is it "&#13" in HTML?

Comment: Usually it is `\n`, but I'm not sure if that automatically recognizes both windows and linux returns, but I think it does. (and if it doesn't, you will just have an extra symbol that noone sees ^^) If I remember correctly the "carriage return and reset" would be `\n\r`, but no guarantee for that